# Triggering a key event in IE11 for angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test that when a using presses Enter in an input a certain chain of events happen. In my test file I have a simple method which triggers the `Enter` key on the input element;

```
  function TriggerEnterEventOnInput() {
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { 'key': 'Enter' });
    fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

It works fine in Chrome but if you try this in IE you get a nice error saying;

> Object doesn't support this action

This is because IE doesn't support the KeyboardEvent constructor. Is there any other way to trigger specific key events, preferably without using plugins like JQuery?!

Answer (score 2):

As the KeyboardEvent constructor is not available on IE, you can use following snippet which works on all browsers.

```
 TriggerEnterEventOnInput() {

    let event: KeyboardEvent;

    try {
      event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { 'key': 'Enter', 'bubbles': true });
    }
    catch {
      event = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
      event.initKeyboardEvent(
          'keyup', // event name e.g. keyup, keydown, keypress
          false, // canBubbleArg
          false, // cancelableArg
          null, // viewArg
          'Enter', // your keyboard press value
          0, // locationArg
          '', // modifiersListArg
          false, // repeat
          '' // locale
      );
    }
    fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

> Be aware though `document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent")` is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent

Comment: I have read a tons of answers in SO how to simulate pressing ENTER on legacy browsers like IE, and I found your answer finally, which works lika a charm. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I’ll show how to handle various keyboard events. I’ll also show how to identify which specific key was pressed by the user.

First, we should take a moment to be sure we understand the difference between the three different types of general keyboard events:

- keydown: Key has been pressed but not yet released. No default action has been performed yet.
- keypress: Key has been pressed and a character has registered. This event will fire continuously if the key is held down.
- keyup: Pressed key has been released.

Let’s say we are building a web application and want to make an interactive tutorial that we’ve build accessible via an intuitive keyboard shortcut. Anywhere in the application, our users should be able to pull up our help widget via the Ctrl-H key combination.

jQuery

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.which === 72) {
       // open help widget
    }
});
```

Web API

```
< document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.which === 72) {
       // open help widget
    }
});>
```

Nothing is obviously gained, in this instance, with jQuery. Even the syntax is almost identical between the Web API and jQuery.

Registering for other keyboard events follows a similar pattern:

jQuery

```
$(someElement).keypress(function(event) {
    // ...
});

$(someElement).keyup(function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

Web API

```
someElement.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    // ...
});

someElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

For more information about keyboard event properties and browser compatibility